# Do you write methods to return unused values?

Tags: function, language-agnostic, coding-style, return-value

This is (probably) a question of style. If you're writing code and you don't plan on using a method's return value (say, true/false for success/failure), do you still write that method to return a value? ie. if there's a possibility that the return value will be used by someone in future versions of the code?

More generally, do you write methods to *always* or *always not* return values if those methods' return values wouldn't currently be used?

Here's an example: I have a method that deletes an item from a list. If the list is empty, nothing is removed but the current calling code doesn't care whether 0 or 1 items are deleted. Future code revisions might care. Would you write the code like this:

```
void removeItem() {
  if (!m_list.empty()) {
    m_list.pop();
    m_list.pop_back();
  }
}
```

or, as a way to future-proof:

```
bool removeItem() {
  if (!m_list.empty()) {
    m_list.pop();
    m_list.pop_back();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

In a code review, the reviewers might say the return value is not currently used so get rid of it.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. But if a function has a return value, you *have* to return something from it. Not to do so is undefined behaviour, with the exception of `main()`, which has an implicit `return 0;`. This applies to C++, as the question had that tag before.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've edited. Does that make it more clear? It's more a programming paradigm, so I consider it language-agnostic.

Comment: Not really language agnostic. In many languages you would throw an exception to signal failure or error. Other languages don't have exceptions.

Comment: This question is not language agnostic. In many programming languages, this question simply does not make sense.

Comment: And in some languages, _every_ method has a return value which the caller may use, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the [YAGNI principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) I don't think you should return anything that might possibly be needed in the far future maybe optional tentatively. In the future, you will need something else anyway. If you plan for a bool today, you will need a double next year and all the work preparing for the future bool was wasted.

Implement to the specs. Not more, not less.